# Why isn't the container passed to my worker function being passed by reference?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, pass-by-reference

I was under the impression that python passed objects by reference, so logically (I thought), passing a dictionary to a thread's worker function would allow me to set new key-value pairs that would be preserved after the worker function had returned.  Unfortunately, it seems as though I am wrong!

Without further ado, here's a test case:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


def work_fn(dictionary, dfield):
    dictionary[dfield] = True


class Worker(Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try:
                func(*args, **kargs)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
            self.tasks.task_done()


class ThreadPool(object):
    """Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue"""
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)

        for i in range(num_threads):
            Worker(self.tasks)

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        """Add a task to the queue"""
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.tasks.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ThreadPool(4)

    data = [{} for _ in range(10)]
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        pool.add_task(work_fn, d, str(i))

    pool.wait_completion()

    for d in data:
        print d.keys()
```

What is actually going on here?

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: You can modify dictionaries passed to function. The problem is `self.tasks` is a `Queue`, so the `self.tasks.join()` call in `wait_completion()` in isn't going to work. Regardless, you never even call it, so all the task are probably not finished.

Comment: @martineau, the code has been updated.  I omitted `pool.wait_completion()` from my example (accidentally), but I do call it in the production code.  Why wouldn't `Queue.join` work?

Comment: `join()` won't work because a `Queue` isn't a task.

Comment: @martineau, could you be more explicit?  What do you mean by "Queue isn't a task"?  What should I actually be doing differently, in concrete terms?  It would be especially nice if you could provide an answer with some code. Thanks!

Comment: Make `wait_completion(()` call `join()` on each thread in the `self.tasks` queue -- or not return while any of them `is_alive()`.

Comment: P.S. You might also be able to use `threading.enumerate()` to determine when they're all finished in `wait_completion(()`.

Comment: @martineau, Okay, I'll definitely give those approaches a try, but I'm still very confused by the example at the bottom of the [Queue documentation page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).  Where's the difference between this example and my code?  What am I failing to grok, here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24904/discussion-between-blz-and-martineau)

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. `Queues` do have a `join()` method, as do `thread` objects. However joining one won't work because nothing is taking task threads off the queue when they're done. The simplest thing you can probably do is just make `wait_completion()` keep calling `threading.enumerate()` until it returns 0 which will indicate they're all finished.

Comment: You're also going to need a `lock` or something to synchronize all those worker threads which are trying to update the shared dictionary at the same time.

Comment: @martineau, there's no shared dictionary, here.  There's a separate dictionary being passed to each `Worker`... or have I missed something?

Comment: "I was under the impression that python passed objects by reference" No, objects are not values in Python. All values in Python are references (i.e. pointers to objects). And everything in Python is passed by value. It is true by passing a reference to a dictionary object will allow you to use methods on the dictionary to mutate it.

Comment: @newacct, I'm not sure I see the distinction.  We're essentially passing around pointers, no?  Doesn't reference == pointer?  Either way, don't python objects *behave* as if they were passed by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are waiting for the tasks to finish before printing the results.  It seems like you need to do the collection of results in a subsequent loop after spawning the jobs.

Comment: Nice catch!  Actually I do wait for the threads to finish in my production code (example has been updated).  I'm still getting similar results.  Are you saying there's no way to modify a dictionary in-place from within a thread?  If so, I'm rather surprised...  **EDIT:** Actually, I just figured out what you're saying.  The point is that the thread isn't necessarily done with it's work by the time I print 'dict.keys()'